# Multi platform archive library needed

Tags: c++, archive

I search for free("LGPL" or something similar), multi platform archive library (c/c++)

Wanted features:

1) Multi platform (gcc/msvc)

2)read and write

3)Unicode (not 100% necessary )

4)encryption (not 100% necessary )

5)compression (not 100% necessary )

6) Good documentation

I found some libraries but they are read only or not really free or something else

zlib (compress only i think)

zziplib (read only i think)

PhysicalFS (read only)

LZO (GPL 2+)

LZMA SDK(can't build on linux)

Comment: Are you looking for a specific archive format or just anything?

Comment: If you have to say "i think" then you didn't do enough research on your own.

Comment: I search a lot but don't find this info (for example zziplib (read only i think)) in documentation.I find this in forums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you look at
http://libarchive.github.com/

Take a look at https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/LibarchiveFormats for supported formats. Works on posix and windows.

But I would normaly go with zlib. The most portabel lib in the world.

Comment: Thanks i will make some researches and then I will response